# Financial data group by date, even if data is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pulling financial figures from SQL for a given month, and I want to get a dataset with each day of the month, and the figures next to it. Some days the figures will be null, which is why if I perform a query with a group on the date, it returns only rows with data.

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Date       ║ DailyActual ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1/02/2017  ║ 14397.59091 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2/02/2017  ║ 29723.37273 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3/02/2017  ║ 32436.31818 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 6/02/2017  ║ 27048.32727 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 7/02/2017  ║ 30690.66364 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 8/02/2017  ║ 32267.42727 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 9/02/2017  ║ 29592.29091 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 10/02/2017 ║ 31740.49091 ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I'm looking to return data like so

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Date       ║ DailyActual ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1/02/2017  ║ 14397.59091 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2/02/2017  ║ 29723.37273 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3/02/2017  ║ 32436.31818 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 4/02/2017  ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 5/02/2017  ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 6/02/2017  ║ 27048.32727 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 7/02/2017  ║ 30690.66364 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 8/02/2017  ║ 32267.42727 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 9/02/2017  ║ 29592.29091 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 10/02/2017 ║ 31740.49091 ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 11/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 12/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 13/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 14/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 15/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 16/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 17/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 18/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 19/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 20/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 21/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 22/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 23/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 24/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 25/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 26/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 27/02/2017 ║             ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 28/02/2017 ║             ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I managed to write a query which would select all the days in the month, but I couldn't get this to join with my financial query?

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME= '20170201'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '20170228'
;WITH Calender AS 
(
    SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalanderDate + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE CalanderDate + 1 <= @endDate
)
SELECT CalanderDate
FROM Calender
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

My current query as per my first table, is as follows

```
SELECT ci.InvoiceDate, SUM(CASE WHEN ci.Type = 'Invoice' THEN ci.Total ELSE -ci.Total END) / 1.1 
  FROM CustomerInvoice ci 
  WHERE ci.IsVoided = 0 AND ci.InvoiceDate BETWEEN '20170201' AND '20170228'
  GROUP BY ci.InvoiceDate
```

Comment: Left join to a calendar table. This question have been answered a lot of times on the internet.

Comment: @ATC you mean left join to the financial table? hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd `left join` from the calendar table to the financial table.  This will include all rows from the calendar table, optionally repeated for any row in the financial table.  For example:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME= '20170201'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '20170228'
;
WITH    Calendar AS 
        (
        SELECT  @startDate AS CalendarDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CalendarDate + 1 FROM Calendar
        WHERE   CalendarDate + 1 <= @endDate
        )
SELECT  CalendarDate,       
        SUM(CASE WHEN ci.Type = 'Invoice' THEN ci.Total ELSE -ci.Total END) / 1.1 
FROM    Calendar
LEFT JOIN
        CustomerInvoice ci
ON      ci.InvoiceDate = CalendarDate
        and ci.IsVoided = 0
GROUP BY
        CalendarDate
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks... so obvious, really!

Comment: @BrendanGooden: Good catch, grouping on `ci.InvoiceDate` wasn't going to work!

Answer (score 1):

After you have created the CTE called *Calendar* with all the dates, you need to make a LEFT JOIN with *CustomerInvoice* table. Don't forget to add a extra condition in the CASE statement. Because this LEFT JOIN will fill all non matched (by date) *ci.type* with NULL values.

```
   SELECT c.CalanderDate AS Date
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ci.Type IS NULL THEN 0
                   WHEN ci.Type = 'Invoice' THEN ci.Total 
                   ELSE - ci.Total END
             ) / 1.1 AS DailyActual
     FROM Calender AS c
LEFT JOIN CustomerInvoice ci ON c.CalanderDate = ci.InvoiceDate
                            AND ci.IsVoided = 0
 GROUP BY c.CalanderDate
```

Comment: This doesn't work? Still only shows rows that include data from CustomerInvoice

Comment: Filtering should be done at JOIN or WHERE. Checked and working.

Comment: Should be grouped on calendar date, not invoice date

Comment: Oopss. corrected it. Got confused as it was showing the result with InvoiceDate.